# Will Azure Data Lake Store Gen2 support PolyBase from on-prem SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-lake

So Azure Data Lake Store Gen2 is pretty much a merger between Blob Storage and Data Lake Store:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/data-lake-storage/introduction

SQL Server on-prem PolyBase allowed connection to Blob Storage, but not to ADLS Gen1.

Will PolyBase for on-prem SQL Server allow connection to ADLS Gen2?

Comment: Want to see if this is still an outstanding question. Please review the following doc as connections to ADLS Gen2 is supported but it depends on the direction of data flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yup, still outstanding. I know that Gen2 is supported in read-mode. But Gen2 is built on top of / merged with Blob Storage, which supported read-write. So will Gen2 support rw from on-prem SQL?